# Makefile, sqare brackets built-in, variable expansion and command substitution

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution, gnu-make

To embrace the DRY (Don’t Repeat Yourself) principle, I sometimes need to share pieces of shell commands in a **Makefile**. So there is a recipe somewhere in that file like:

```bash
shell=/bin/bash
# …
.ONESHELL:
run:
    # Create bash sub-shell «cmd» var, holding a built-in test as a string
    @cmd='[ $$(grep -iE _dev </etc/hosts | wc -l) -eq 0 ]'
    # "$$" tells make to escape the dollar sign. So echoing …
    @echo "$$cmd"
    # gives «[ $(grep -iE _dev </etc/hosts | wc -l) -eq 0 ]» as I expected
    # I need this variable to be expanded and interpreted as a real
    # built-in square bracket test, so I wrote
    @$$cmd && echo "Pass ! do more magical things …" || true
```

I expected *make* to escape `$` sign `$$cmd` ⇒ `$cmd` which would in turn be expanded within *bash* context into the bracket test unquoted string … right ?
But I get an error instead `/bin/bash: line 2: [: too many arguments`

Does anybody have an idea of why this error is being raised ?
Why bash is not given the bracket test I expect ?
`[ $(grep -iE _dev </etc/hosts | wc -l) -eq 0 ] && echo "Pass!"`

Thank you.

Comment: I don't speak fluent makefile, but is 'strong quoting' as opposed to "weak quoting" a thing in them?

Comment: Quoting doesn't exist in make context, quotes are output as is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23332194

Comment: `make run` prints "Pass ! do more magical things …"  with GNU Make 3.81

Comment: And why would it print "line 2"?   Is somehow the newline from `wc` getting through?

Comment: @RobertL I'm using Make 4.1, I don't know what it is saying the error accured on line 2. I think dave_thompson_085 got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable and command substitions in the shell occur after deciding on command boundaries, and parsing redirections (and assignments). You can put a program name and/or arguments in a variable and substitute them, but not pipes or redirection or other substitutions including `$( command )` or assignments or shell keywords like `if` and `for`.

In this case you could eliminate the pipe and wc and substitution by changing the command and reversing your test:

```
cmd='grep -qi _dev /etc/hosts' # note file as argument not redirection
$$cmd || do_blah
```

where the substituted grep command fails (silently) if it doesn't find any match in the file, and if it fails do_blah is executed.

In general to use shell syntax (not just program arguments) in a substituted value, you must use `eval` to execute the substituted value (or values), or else run a child shell like `sh -c "$$cmd"` (substitute other shell if needed depending on environment and/or command).

Answer (score 0):

A `Makefile` is not a shell script. The entire thing could be more simply and cleanly written as

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
grep -q -iE _dev /etc/hosts
echo pass
...
```

Comment: Sure, make is not bash. You are right, by default make executes each line in its own sub-shell process. But I decorated the target with `.ONESHELL` directive which tells *make* to use a single bash process for the entire target recipe, this is how one is able to reference a variable defined on previous line.